# Typing Pinyin with tone marks doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I have a Macbook Air.  Running El Capitan with British keyboard layout.  I have enabled Chines Simplified Pinyin input.  I am trying to type the tone marks.  For example, pressing <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>u</kbd> is supposed to produce ū.  This doesn't work however.  Any advice?

I have seen mentions of US Extended Keyboard or ABC extended keyboard layout as being the culprit.  While this makes 0 sense to me, I have replaced the British layout with this ABC Extended one.  While now I can type the accented characters in it, they still don't work in Pinyin.  This is extremely annoying.

Comment: I thought I had this problem too to begin with but suddenly it just started working, after I played around with the keys for a while. I'm not sure what suddenly changed.

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to type Latin script pinyin, then ABC Extended is the right keyboard.  Chinese Pinyin input is only for Chinese script and does not use tone marks.